# Attempt by security transparent method 'x' to access security critical method 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(System.Object)' failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have a MVC application created by Devexpress.I get this error on

www.site.com/Accoun/Login

```
Attempt by security transparent method 'DevExpress.XtraScheduler.Native.   
FullTrustAppointmentMultiClientCacheItem.CreateHandler()' to access security critical method 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(System.Object)' failed.

Assembly 'DevExpress.XtraScheduler.v13.2.Core, Version=13.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' is partially trusted, 
which causes the CLR to make it entirely security transparent regardless of any transparency annotations in the assembly itself.  
In order to access security critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted.
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite hard to suggest something without understanding all the aspects of this situation. You should [report this issue](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create) directly to DevExpress Support team and provide them with details. I believe their guys can diagnose the error and point you into the right direction in Scheduler usage in MVC environment.

Related support-article: [ASPxScheduler and Medium Trust](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q452929)

Comment: Solved. DevExpress.Data.Helpers.SecurityHelper.ForcePartialTrustMode=true in Global.asax Application_Start() function.